# 2D Unity (for graphics & ease of use): Flash? Haxe?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 2d, haxe, vector-graphics

I'm planning on making a little game. And I'm looking for an engine. Basically what I want is Unity, but then 2D. It's a very interface heavy game, stylized, so what I need is an engine (or similar) in which it's easy to draw lines, primitives and text (and bitmaps, though that's less important.) The game will have a game world, though you'll never directly see it. All you'll get is a bunch of information about it (text, lines, graphs, ...)

I know you could use Unity to make 2D games, though for what I have in mind it's not optimal and the way objects work in Unity isn't really how I want to structure my game. (I've worked a lot in Unity and absolutely love it, though I don't think it's the right tool for this game.)

What I love about Unity is that you can just build for any platform, with a single click, and it just works. It also already has it's own way of building your gameobjects, and since I'm making something very different, I don't want this. I need more control over the objects and actually only want the engine to draw stuff.

I was thinking about using Flash, ActionScript3. It should be very good at drawing lines and text. And hopefully just as easy to build.

I also checked out HTML5 and javascript, using KineticJS, which can draw lines and primites very easily (pretty much exactly like I want it), though I hate javascript and want more structured code. Maybe it's just me that I can't get javascript to be clean enough for my taste, but well, that's something we'll have to live with then :P

My question now is, since I never used flash. What are your thoughts on this. Is it perfect for this kind of stylized text-based games? Is it easy to build (I'm using FlashDevelop since that's a free way to make flash stuff)? On top of that, can I use a single code base for Windows and Mac (maybe even iOS, Android or other, though that's less important)?

Or maybe you have another suggestion I could check out? (I already checked out a bunch of other question here, though none were really helpful. So yea it's another 'I'm looking for an engine' question, so don't kill me for that. I already did quite a bit of looking around, though would love some more input from others.)

Edit1: I've been looking around some more and found Haxe (http://haxe.org/) seems promising, can anyone recommend this or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for what you want to do, flash would not be an optimal tool. The beauty of flash and what it was designed to do is to separate and combine what a graphical artist does and what a programmer does.

You see, you have Flash as the tool where you align, position and import/draw graphics and do complex animations. And then you export those as assets and work with the graphical resources from ActionScript. This means that a programmer "never" has to worry about positioning objects and the visual appearance of the game. The programmer only have to provide the functionality for what should happen when stuff happens (buttons are clicked, animations are complete etc).

It sounds as if your game are more in the "techy" family, where you will be working alone, and you want to draw primitives yourself and there will be a lot of text on the screen.

Flash was never intended to be a tool to work with loads of text and doing stuff the techy way, it was created to make it easy to work with loads of graphical resources in a structured way where the programmer doesn't have to worry that much about the graphical content.

If my assumptions of what you want to do is correct, you would be better off working with JS. It would be better suited since you are working with few complex graphical assets, are interested in cross platform support and basically wants to work with loads of text.

Comment: Allright I see you point (though Descalon tells me it's not true, but still xD) I have worked quite a bit with JS before, and I find it fine for smaller projects, though when it gets larger I really dislike this as a language. Perhaps you know something else that's not JS? :P

Comment: Kind of hard to suggest something without knowing how you want to work, and what you would like to do (some design drafts or similar stuff). I mean you could use flash and as3, it's a lovely language and easy to work with and customize graphics. I just wouldn't use it for a project centered around texts and primitives. I dont know what else to use if JS doesn't suit you, I would have gone for that and cursed at sucky coding IDEs given the premises :) But then again, I haven't really done anything big and complex in JS. Everything else I think about are centered around graphical assets

Comment: I just found Dart, that seems very promising. Ever used that?

Answer (score 1):

I think Flash/AC3 would fit perfectly, especially if you're using FlashDevelop. 
To comment on Daniel MesSer:

> This means that a programmer "never" has to worry about positioning objects and the visual appearance of the game. The programmer only have to provide the functionality for what should happen when stuff happens (buttons are clicked, animations are complete etc).

This just is not true. If you're work at a company that solely uses Flash CS this might be the case. But with FlashDevelop you've got a fully functional IDE. If you look up some third party libraries like Flixel, Citrus Engine or FlashPunk, you'd find something that could fit perfectly to your needs.

Comment: The engines you mentioned are focussed on sprite-based games right?

Comment: Yeah. I thought it was implied that you wanted a sprite-based game. Pardon the assumption.

Comment: No, no, most of my graphics will be lines, primitives and text. Still thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

> I also checked out HTML5 and javascript, using KineticJS, which can draw lines and primites very easily (pretty much exactly like I want it), though I hate javascript and want more structured code.

Write objectoriented javascript :-) I'm a oop-maniac, but I'm starting to find the beauty of js too. It IS possible to write beautiful code even there! ;-)

Regarding flash and AS3, It would be possible, and probably pretty "easy" to use. I started programming using AS2 (well some other stuff before that as well). But personally I dont think flash is the right way to go. Flash have reached it's expiery-date a long time ago.

There are several games coded in HTML5 and KineticJS. You can find some examples on www.kineticjs.com. With HTML5 and kinetic, you'll also be able to make it work for multiple platforms at once.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Yea I already write OOjs, though what bugs me the most is no type checking, very annoying :P And there is some kind of workaround, with Google Closure, but that's far from perfect.
And concerning Flash: that's what I was afraid of, expired :(
I also just found Haxe, any idea about that?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any experience of Haxe. I would go with HTML5 and Kinetic/some other library. Mostly because it's cool ;-)